# Mandrill only recognize a few of my merge tags?

Tags: php, api, merge, mandrill

I am using the Mandrill PHP-API Class to send bulk mail to my clients. And was wondering why dose Mandrill only recognize a few of my 'recipient_metadata' Merge Tags?

The Mandrill Api Request is :

```
{
 "message": {
 "from_email": "me@example.com",
 "from_name": "Bengwela Stream",
 "headers": {
   "Reply-To": "me@example.com"
 },
 "important": false,
 "track_opens": true,
 "track_clicks": true,
 "auto_text": null,
 "auto_html": null,
        "inline_css": null,
        "url_strip_qs": null,
        "preserve_recipients": false,
        "tracking_domain": null,
        "signing_domain": null,
        "tags": [
            "CODE"
        ],
        "merge": true,
        "metadata": {
            "sendtype": "demorun"
        },
        "to": [
            {
                "email": "to@example.com",
                "name": "Bob "
            }
        ],
        "subject": "CODE L1",
        "recipient_metadata": [
            {
                "rcpt": "bob@example.com",
                "vars": [
                    {
                        "name": "A",
                        "content": 3
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "email",
                        "content": "bob@example.com"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "invoice",
                        "content": "123456"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "SITE",
                        "content": "http://example.com"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
"html": " <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \" ....Complex....   *|A|* *|email|* *|invoice|* *|SITE|* ",
"text": " *|A|* *|email|* *|invoice|* *|SITE|* ",
},
    "async": true,
    "ip_pool": null,
    "send_at": null,
    "key": "123456456645"
}
```

---

But in both any TEXT and EMAIL Live send, only  *|A|*  *|email|* are replaced.
I'm most probably messed some thing up here. But I can't see what. :)
Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To populate merge tags (the `*|SOMETHING|*`, you actually want to use the `merge_vars` and `global_merge_vars` parameters instead of the metadata parameters. Metadata allows you to add information to the message, but it's *only* for your tracking/analytics (more on metadata [here](http://help.mandrill.com/entries/21786413-Using-Custom-Message-Metadata)). Nothing from the metadata parameters is used to populate merge tags or content in the message.  The `*|EMAIL|*` merge tag is special - if you don't provide a value, we'll automatically fill in the recipient's email address by default.

So, in your API call, you should just be able to replace `recipient_metadata` with `merge_vars` and have those merge tags get populated as expected.

For more on working with merge tags, check out the KB article here: http://help.mandrill.com/entries/21678522

And if you're still running in to issues, you can contact support to look at the actual API call(s) you're making. Just click the 'Help' link in the footer when logged in to your account.